# Prove that the given metric is positive-definite

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, tensor-calculus

I want to prove that given a timelike vector field $V^a$ and a metric $g_{ab}$ on a manifold, the metric given by $\hat{g}_{ab} = g_{ab} + 2V_aV_b$ is positive definite. Here's what I've thought of: we need to show that $\hat{g}_{ab}U^aU^b>0$ for any vector $U$. I know that $V^aV^bU_aU_b$ is positive. I do not know what to do of the $g_{ab}U^aU^b$ term. I tried completing the square, but it's not possible because of $2 (U \cdot V)^2$ term. Any help would be appreciated. I guess I'm missing something trivial.

Comment: A suggestion: use a pseudo orthonormal basis of $g$ with time unit vector parallel to $V$. What is the matrix expression of $\hat{g}$ in that basis?

Comment: In full generality the statement is not true. Take as $g_{ab}$ the Minkowski metric and $V_{a}$ such that the only non-zero component is the temporal one and in absolute value smaller than one. Then $\hat{g}_{ab}$ is still Lorentzian.

Comment: @Valter Moretti, I did not get you, what is a pseudo orthonormal basis?

Comment: Also, there was an error in the question, have corrected it now.

Comment: It is a base s which diagonalises $g$. $V$ must satisfy $g(V,V)=-1$.. Complete $V$ to a basis of $g$ which diagonalizes it. In this basis $\hat{g}$ is represented by $\delta_{ab}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every **unit** timelike vector $V$  can be completed to a basis which canonically diagolizes the Lorenzian metric $g$. In other words,   its matrix form turns out to be $diag(-1, 1, 1, 1)$ in that basis. It is sufficient to add a triple of spacelike unit mutually orthogonal and orthogonal to $V$ further vectors. Evidently, referring to that basis, $V^a\equiv (1, 0,0,0)$. As a consequence $V_a\equiv (-1,0,0,0)$ and $$V_aV_b\equiv diag(1,0,0,0).$$ Therefore $\hat{g}$ has, in that basis, the form
$$diag(-1,1,1,1) + 2diag(1,0,0,0)= diag (1,1,1,1)$$
This is the canonical form of every Euclidean metric, i.e., positive defined.

If $V$ is timelike but not unit, the similarly associated Euclidean metric is
$$g(X,Y)-2\frac{g(V,X)g(V,Y)}{g(V,V)}.$$